# Android button doesn't change when pressed

Tags: android, image, button, background, selector

I have a problem when i click on button it doesn't change the background image

this is the btn_states.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

and activity_main.xml

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_states"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

And the MainActivity.class

```
 final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_states);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: are these:
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" android:state_focused="true"/>
inside a selector

Comment: Reverse the order of your states. They are checked in order, and the first state in your example matches all possible state sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<selector>` element, which inflates to a `StateListDrawable`, finds the most appropriate drawable for a given state set by linearly searching through a set of state specifications. It will select the first `<item>` that matches the state set.

In your example, the first `<item>` has no states specified, either inclusive (`true`) or exclusive (`false`), so it matches all state sets. As a result, the search will end early and the drawable for the first `<item>` will used for all possible state sets.

Instead, you could order it like this:

```
<selector>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" />
</selector>
```